# Cant upload images to s3 bucket with rails app and paperclip

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, environment-variables, paperclip

Hi can anyone point me in the direction of what I am doing wrong. I am trying to upload an image to an S3 bucket in EU region, Ireland, using a rails application in development. This is the error I am getting the error

- SocketError in ProductsController
- getaddrinfo: nodename nor servname provided, or not known

On the following line : TCPSocket.open(conn_address, conn_port, @local_host, @local_port)

I am using the aws-sdk gem and paperclip 4.2.

Here are some code snippets

In:

```
config/enviroments/development.rb

config.paperclip_defaults = {
  :storage => :s3,
  :s3_host_name => "s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com",
  :s3_credentials => {
  :bucket => 'S3_BUCKET_NAME',
  :access_key_id => 'AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID',
  :secret_access_key => 'AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'
 }
```

In

```
 config/aws.yml
    development:
       AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID: "xxx"
       AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY: "xxx"
       S3_BUCKET_NAME: "xxx"
       s3_host_name: 's3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com'
```

In my model

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base

  validates :avatar,
    attachment_content_type: { content_type: /\Aimage\/.*\Z/ },
    attachment_size: { less_than: 5.megabytes }

  has_attached_file :avatar, styles: {
    thumb: '100x100>',
    square: '200x200#',
    medium: '300x300>'
  }
end
```

What am I missing? I have looked at every example I could find online and tried to adjust but with no luck.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I've solved this by hardcoding the AWS credentials into the development.rb file. So it looks like the problem was the aws.yml file wasn't being loaded, does anyone have any idea why or how to solve this?

Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
#config/enviroments/development.rb

config.paperclip_defaults = {
  :storage => :s3,
  :s3_host_name => "s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com",
  :s3_credentials => {
  :bucket => ENV["S3_BUCKET_NAME"],
  :access_key_id => ENV["AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID"],
  :secret_access_key => ENV["AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY"]
 }
```

Comment: is the selected answer what your suggestion was?